# Не хватает длины массива в цикле

Tags: javascript

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
    let newArray = [];
    newArray.push(arr.slice(0, size));
    let pre = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length ; i+=size) {
        pre.push(arr.splice(size, size));
    }
    console.log( arr.length )
    return newArray.concat(pre)

}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2));
```

---

Функция должна вернуть -

*`[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8]]`*

А возвращает -

*`[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]`*

*То-есть, функция должна разбивать массив(первый аргумент) на группы по длине(второй аргумент) и вернуть их в виде двухмерного массива*

В итоге я поковырялся и добавил к `arr.length + 4` , и все вернуло как надо,но тогда возникает проблема с другими примерами массивов в функции(например этой  *`chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2)`*  ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {

    let pre = [];

    while(arr.length > 0) {
        pre.push(arr.splice(0, size));
    }
    console.log( arr.length )
    return pre;

}
```

Comment: Да , по-сути тоже самое что и  сделать, `let i = size` в `for-e`

Comment: Да, но зачем создавать еще одну переменную? Да и while нагляднее как по мне

Comment: Тоже об этом подумал,полностью согласен

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит использовать `splice`. Массивы в js передаются по ссылке, таким образом вы разрушаете исходный массив.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  let chunks = [];
  for (let i=0, n=arr.length; i<n; i+=size) {
      let chunk = arr.slice(i,i+size);
      chunks.push(chunk);
  }
  return chunks;
}

let res = chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```